# Derivative of the Fejer Kernel?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I'm looking to calculate the derivative of the Fejer kernel:
$$
F_n(x) = \frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac x2\right)}\right)^2
$$
However, I'm running into some real difficulty with the calculation. Supposedly I should get $F_n' = 2n\sin(nx)F_{n-1}(x)$ (or something like this), but I'm not getting anywhere near this result and I'm not sure why.

Just via rote calculation, using $\left(\frac uv\right)' = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$, we calculate
$$
\begin{align}
F_n' & = \frac1{n+1}\frac{\sin((n+1)x/2)}{\sin^3(x/2)}\left[(n+1)\cos((n+1)x/2)\sin(x/2) - \sin((n+1)x/2)\cos(x/2)\right] \\
& = \frac1{n+1}\frac{\sin((n+1)x/2)}{\sin^3(x/2)}\left[n\cos((n+1)x/2)\sin(x/2)-\sin(nx/2)\right]
\end{align}
$$
where the simplification on the second line is simply $\sin(x - y) = \sin x\cos y - \cos x\sin y$.

Frankly I have no clue what to do from here. If the formula $F_n' = 2(n+1)\sin((n+1)x)F_{n-1}(x)$ is true, then supposedly
$$
\frac{2(n+1)}{n}\frac{\sin((n+1)x)\sin^2(nx/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)} = \frac1{n+1}\frac{\sin((n+1)x/2)}{\sin^3(x/2)}[n\cos((n+1)x/2)\sin(x/2)-\sin(nx/2)]
$$
but I see absolutely no reason why this should be the case. In fact, plugging both sides into Desmos for some $n$ gives completely different graphs, validating my suspicions.

Is there *actually* a nice formula for the derivative of the Fejer kernel? If so, what is it? I can't see how to simplify my result further.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried working with the series representation for the Fejer kernel instead of the closed form? (I haven't tried, and don't know whether it would be easier or not.)

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't yield particularly useful results either, and also assuming the formula incorporated a $\sin$ term made me think this representation of the Fejer kernel was the most practical for the calculation.